# Old Red Hat Linux 5.2 on VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, redhat-enterprise-linux

I am trying to install and run Redhat 5.2 on a VirtualBox VM. This is NOT RHEL; This is the old Redhat 5.2 from before the Fedora project and was first released in 1997. While going through the installation steps, I am continually failing to pick the proper Video Card for it. When it goes to probe for resolutions, it just freezes...

Does anyone know what Video Card VirtualBox emulates? Is there any way to get a specific video card presented to the installation wizard? Are there any tips for troubleshoot this further and finding extra information that may be useful?

[image: Redhat 5.2 XConfiguration]

Comment: The X video configuration is stored in /etc/X11/XF86config.  Another way to set its contents is with `xf86config`.  With some trial and error, I was able to get a 320x200 display working with a ps/2 mouse, but it needed a bigger display to do anything really useful.  Using Qemu might produce better results.

Comment: Is there is a third party X server that works on Red Hat 5.x and supports VESA BIOS Extensions? The beta of SDD for Linux https://web.archive.org/web/20011031030638/http://www.scitechsoft.com:80/down_sdd_linux.html is about the right vintage, but when I tried it on RH 5.0 in VirtualBox it detected the `80EE:BEEF` device and tried but failed to load `vbeaf.drv` according to its `/usr/lib/nucleus/config/nucleus.log`

Answer (score 3):

You can get a basic VGA driver to work(640x480 with 16 colours). NOTE: some programs will not work in this mode.

Here is how you do it:

1. As root type 'setup'. The dailogs here use the same controls as the ones used when installing RedHat 5.2.
2. Select Xconfigurator
3. Hit 'ok'
4. Choose 'Unsupported VGA compatible'(you can push 'page down to make it a lot easier).
5. Select 'custom' for a monitor
6. Hit 'ok' on the next screen.
7. I don't think the monitor setting matter to much. I choose "monitor that can do 1280x1024@76Hz"
8. Choose '50-70' on the next screen.
9. Choose 'Don't Probe'
10. Choose '8 meg' for memory
11. For clockchip choose 'IBM RGB 51x/52x(autodected)'
12. Hit 'ok' on the last screen and then hit 'quit'
13. You can now run X by typing startx.(though running X as root is not recommended).

Comment: If I had an old SVGA X-server  I could probably get SVGA.

Answer (score 1):

From the [virtualbox manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#idp54468208)

> Graphics. The VirtualBox graphics device (sometimes referred to as
>   VGA device) is, unlike nearly all other emulated devices, not based on
>   any physical counterpart. It is a simple, synthetic device which
>   provides compatibility with standard VGA and several extended
>   registers used by the VESA BIOS Extensions (VBE).

RH 5.2 uses an older kernel and compatibility isn't assured even if you could build the video card driver yourself.

In short, you're likely to be out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

You could try plain VESA.  I recently used that to install Mandrake 9.1.  Granted, that's a little later than Red Hat 5.2.  If you get it to work, you're likely to be limited to 1024x768.